# How to detect how many stairs are there in an image using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to detect how many stairs I have in an image using OpenCV with C++, I've tried to do:

1-Binarization.

2-Canny Filter.

3-Hough Filter.

4-Connected Components.

I didn't get good results, do you have any idea of which methodology should I follow?

Thank you in advance.

Here is an image example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My algorithm approach is simply like that; finding the lines of each stair will give us the stair number. To achieve that **Houghline Transform can** be used. You should read the documents which are linked below to be able to understand the parameter logic of the HoughLinesP function.

**First problem will come accross:** Houghline transform will give you many lines. To get the available lines, I eliminate the lines whose **y-axis** values are close to each other. I decided this threshold by considering the minimum distance between two stairs.

*Note: To work on an image which is taken by vertical(90 degree) to stairs will give more better results.*

Here are these steps, results, and code:

- Apply [GauusianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur) to blur the image. The reason of GauusianBlur choosing instead of the [others](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html) I believe that GaussianBlur has a good combination with **houghline transform**.
- Apply [Canny Edge detection](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html).
- Convert image to BGR format.
- Apply [HoughLinesP](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb) and find all possible lines
- Apply the algorithm approach which is explained above.
- Get the results.

Code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("/home/rnd/Desktop/photos/stairs.png");
    imshow("Source",img);

    //Apply Gaussian blur to get good results
    GaussianBlur(img,img,Size(5,5),0,0);

    Mat dst, out_img,control;
    Canny(img, dst, 80, 240, 3);
    cvtColor(dst, out_img, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    cvtColor(dst, control, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    vector<int> y_keeper_for_lines;
    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 30, 40, 5 );

    for( size_t i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        line( control, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    Vec4i l = lines[0];
    line( out_img, Point(0, l[1]), Point(img.cols, l[1]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    y_keeper_for_lines.push_back(l[1]);

    int okey = 1;
    int stair_counter = 1;

    for( size_t i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        for(int m:y_keeper_for_lines)
        {
            if(abs(m-l[1])<15)
                okey = 0;

        }
        if(okey)
        {
            line( out_img, Point(0, l[1]), Point(img.cols, l[1]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
            y_keeper_for_lines.push_back(l[1]);
            stair_counter++;
        }
        okey = 1;

    }
    putText(out_img,"Stair number:" + to_string(stair_counter),Point(40,60),FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1.5,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    imshow("Before", img);
    imshow("Control", control);
    imshow("detected lines", out_img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

After Gaussian:

[image]

HoughLinesP before algorithm:

[image]

After algorithm:

[image]

Comment: Thank you my friend! 
I'm new in the field of image processing and computer vision, you're really of a great help!

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain interesting results as follows:

- compute the pixel sums horizontally; this will give you a profile (1D signal);
- compute the derivative of the profile;
- detect the peaks; they are positive and negative, alternatively, one of each per step.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I've never thought of this method!!
It presses me to try it!